# What means "Invalid date specified" on querying of Google Analytics API

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-analytics-api

I query Google Analytics API from outta Google Sheets.

My `endDate` I define in `B2` as `=today()`, my `startDate` I define in `B3` as `=B2-30`.

`B2` and `B3` cells I formatted manually as date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

On running a query I get an error:

{ "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Invalid Date specified: Wed Oct 27 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } }

What is wrong with my date input?

I have one guess, my dates from `B2` and `B3` are transmitted to API instead of format `mm/dd/yyyy` in the format `Wed Oct 27 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)`. If my guess is correct, how can I turn dates into the right format?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the code that is resulting in this error message?

Answer (score 1):

To use dates coming from formula like `=today()` and derivative calculations it doesn't help to re-format values as dates manually, using GSheets formatting function, as I tried it before.

The way I worked it successfully out, is to explicitly make a text from values while formatting it to the needs, like it [explained in the according documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139):

`=TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")` and `=TEXT(B2-30,"yyyy-mm-dd")`